# urldecode is not working for %26 in php which stands for &

Tags: php

I was redirect from an url with %26 which stands for & and i use the `urldecode` function to decode it it donot works may i know why

```
<?php
$a="%26amp%3Bmm%3Dyen";
echo urldecode($a);
```

Updated Question 
OK thankyou guys it works but if that was in url some thing like http://example.com?%26amp%3Bmm%3Dyen i cannot receive thought _REQUEST['mm']; it gives null why?

Comment: Works for me; output is "&amp;mm=yen". Perhaps you also want to use [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) or similar afterward to convert "&amp;" to "&".

Comment: I think you mean it doesn't give you what you expected `&` - it returns `&amp;`

Comment: Works fine for me -- `&amp;mm=yen`

Comment: can u please check the updated question

Answer (score 1):

Since you're encoding "=" as "%3D", the URL doesn't contain a literal "=" character. As a result, "&mm=yen" is all in the argument name, and it has no value. Here's what I get when I `print_r($_REQUEST);`:

```
Array (
  [&mm=yen] =>
)
```

For the value to be passed as you want it, your URL should be:

```
http://example.com?mm=yen
```

You should use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) when you *don't* want special characters to be interpreted as part of the query string.
In this case, you *do* want those characters to be interpreted as part of the query string.